# Can a drupal view return groups that have no associated rows

Tags: drupal-7, grouping, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I have an event view that is grouping an html list by date. The display I want to create is a "week" display with columns for sunday 1st, monday 2nd, tuesday 3rd ... saturday 6th. It's working great when I have an event on every day, but when there are days with no events I get no group (or column) for that day. Is it posible to modify my display to return groups (ie days) that have no results. Am I going to have to do something crazy like create a template for the display that has the 7 columns determines the start date from the exposed filter and the corresponding dates for the every day of the week? blah...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your contextual filter of your View, can you edit the NO RESULTS BEHAVIOUR in advanced settings ?

Comment: Yep I can. How would that help though...I need to add divs that are groups for days that have no events (results).